# What's the importance of cardio in bulking phase?

Tags: cardio, bodybuilding

I know that cardio exercises are really important to fat burn and heart health.

But, for a amateur bodybuilder in bulking phase, cardio are really necessary?

What's the importance of doing it?

Will cardio disturb my gains?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning on competing as a bodybuilder?

Comment: Hi @rrirower thanks for comment. I don't want to compete, but I want to have a nice body and I care about healthy too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cardio is not necessary for anything. It's just good for you (up to a certain point).

Apart from that, it burns calories so usually people use it when they're trying to lose weight. If you're trying to gain weight but still want to take advantage of the benefits of cardio that Sid pointed out, simply eat more so that the calories you burn doing cardio won't affect your bulking phase.

Answer (score 2):

For bulking cardio is not really necessary.However, including moderate amounts cardio exercise into your bulking routine can help control and limit the amount of body fat gained during a bulking phase. Additionally, cardio exercise increases blood flow, delivering more oxygen to your muscles and removing waste products, such as carbon dioxide and lactic acid. The increase in blood flow to the muscles promotes muscle building by delivering fresh nutrients to the muscles needed for growth and aiding in recovery.